# How do I match angle brace > but not >> in vim regular expression search

Tags: regex, vim

I had successfully matched `<` but not preceded (negative look-behind assertion) or followed (negative look-ahead assertion) by `<` by

```
<\@>!<<\@!
```

However while I tried to match a single `>` excluding `>>` the following expression does not work

```
>\@>!>>\@!
```

Why? How should I make the search?

Answer (score 4):

Your `<\@>!<<\@!` regex:

- `<\@>!` lireraly matches `<\@>!`; I think you meant `<\@<!`
- `<` matches the `<`
- `<\@!` matches with zero-width if `<` doesn't match at the current position

It works with `<\@<!<<\@!`.

The syntax for negative look behind assertions is `(atom)\@<!`, where `(atom)` is the thing you don't want to be matched. In this case this is `<`, hence the `<\@<!`.

The syntax for negative look ahead assertions is `(atom)\@!`, where `(atom)` is the thing you don't want to be matched. In this case it's the `<`, hence the `<\@!`.

In PCRE the regex would be:

```
(?<!<)<(?!<)
```

The other regex (`>\@>!>>\@!`) works.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Replace `>` with `<` before the first `!` in the regex will make it work. So the the code on the last line should be
`>\@<!>>\@!`